# Linking multiple tkinter scales created in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

A couple of weeks ago, I started getting into Python mainly because I wanted to learn a programming language, but also to get a little piece of software that I want to use when playing other games.

The program I have started programming consists of a tkinter window with a dynamically updating plot created with matplotlib.
There are a total of 4 sliders, 3 of which are linked.

The goal is to get the different parameters needed for a Hohmann transfer orbit between two planets.

As I am not really experienced with programming in general, I like fooling around doing dirty workarounds or just not write clean code in general just to understand things.

I've successfully made a working version of the program I need, but as I said, it's pretty dirty and barely uses any object, so I took on the task to remake it in an improved way, using objects and less redundant code.

Here is the code of the working version:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import math


def show(slider, slider_value):
    value = slider.get()
    slider_value.delete(0, tk.END)
    slider_value.insert(0, np.round(value, 4))


def is_float(P):
    # checks if entry is float or empty and returns an appropriate boolean
    if P == '':
        return True
    try:
        float(P)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def period(sma, grav_p):
    earth_sma_meters = 149598023E3
    return 2 * np.pi * math.sqrt(((sma * earth_sma_meters) ** 3) / grav_p)


def update_period():
    year_to_sec = 31558149.7635456
    target_period_slider.configure(to=period(target_sma_slider.get(), 1E17) / year_to_sec, from_=period(target_sma_slider.get(), 1E23) / year_to_sec)
    target_period_slider.set(period(target_sma_slider.get(), grav_param_slider.get()) / year_to_sec)


def grav_parameter_parent(sma, period1):
    earth_sma_meters = 149598023E3
    year_to_sec = 31558149.7635456
    return (4 * (math.pi ** 2) * ((sma * earth_sma_meters) ** 3)) / ((period1 * year_to_sec) ** 2)


def update_grav_parameter():
    grav_param_slider.set(grav_parameter_parent(target_sma_slider.get(), target_period_slider.get()))


# Window setup
bgcolor = '#252525'
master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Transfer orbit calculator")
master.geometry("1280x720")
master.config(bg=bgcolor)

# Framing of the window
main_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg=bgcolor)
l_frame = tk.Frame(main_frame, bg=bgcolor)
slider2 = tk.Frame(l_frame, bg=bgcolor)
slider3 = tk.Frame(l_frame, bg=bgcolor)
slider4 = tk.Frame(l_frame, bg=bgcolor)

# Target planet sma slider_frame and entry setup
target_sma_label = tk.Label(slider2, bg=bgcolor, text="The target body's semi-major axis", font=("Arial", 10), fg='white')
target_sma_entry = tk.Entry(slider2, relief='flat', bg='grey', fg='black', validate="key", validatecommand=(master.register(is_float), "%P"))
target_sma_slider = tk.Scale(slider2, sliderrelief='flat', length=600, from_=0.1, to=20, resolution=1E-10, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, bd=0,
                             highlightbackground=bgcolor, troughcolor=bgcolor, bg='#1f77b4', sliderlength=40, showvalue=0, activebackground='#1f77b4',
                             command=lambda event: [update_period(), show(target_sma_slider, target_sma_entry)])
target_sma_slider.set(1.52366)
target_sma_entry.bind("<Return>", lambda event: target_sma_slider.set(target_sma_entry.get()))

target_sma_label.pack(anchor=tk.W)
target_sma_entry.pack(fill=tk.X, anchor=tk.W)
target_sma_slider.pack(anchor=tk.W)

# Target planet period slider_frame and entry setup
target_period_label = tk.Label(slider3, bg=bgcolor, text="The target body's period", font=("Arial", 10), fg='white')
target_period_entry = tk.Entry(slider3, relief='flat', bg='grey', fg='black', validate="key", validatecommand=(master.register(is_float), "%P"))
target_period_slider = tk.Scale(slider3, sliderrelief='flat', length=600, from_=0.01, to=200, resolution=1E-10, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, bd=0,
                                highlightbackground=bgcolor, troughcolor=bgcolor, bg='#1f77b4', sliderlength=40, showvalue=0, activebackground='#1f77b4',
                                command=lambda event: [show(target_period_slider, target_period_entry)])
target_period_slider.set(1.88)
target_period_entry.bind("<Return>", lambda event: [target_period_slider.set(target_period_entry.get()), update_grav_parameter()])
target_period_slider.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event: update_grav_parameter())
target_period_slider.bind("<ButtonRelease>", lambda event: update_grav_parameter())

target_period_label.pack(anchor=tk.W)
target_period_entry.pack(fill=tk.X, anchor=tk.W)
target_period_slider.pack(anchor=tk.W)

# Gravitational parameter of parent slider_frame and entry setup
grav_param_label = tk.Label(slider4, bg=bgcolor, text="The parent's gravitational parameter", font=("Arial", 10), fg='white')
grav_param_entry = tk.Entry(slider4, relief='flat', bg='grey', fg='black', validate="key", validatecommand=(master.register(is_float), "%P"))
grav_param_slider = tk.Scale(slider4, sliderrelief='flat', length=600, from_=1E17, to=1E22, resolution=1E-1, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, bd=0,
                             highlightbackground=bgcolor, troughcolor=bgcolor, bg='#1f77b4', sliderlength=40, showvalue=0, activebackground='#1f77b4',
                             command=lambda event: [update_period(), show(grav_param_slider, grav_param_entry)])
grav_param_slider.set(1.327124400E20)
grav_param_entry.bind("<Return>", lambda event: grav_param_slider.set(grav_param_entry.get()))

grav_param_label.pack(anchor=tk.W)
grav_param_entry.pack(fill=tk.X, anchor=tk.W)
grav_param_slider.pack(anchor=tk.W)

l_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
slider2.grid(pady=5)
slider3.grid(pady=5)
slider4.grid(pady=5)

main_frame.pack(expand=True)

master.mainloop()
```

This uses a cheap workaround using the movement of the mouse to do the calculations when the slider is moved instead of actually calling the function that updates slider3 when slider2 is moved.

I'd like to make it work without using this workaround if possible, using this new version where the sliders are created in a for loop.

```
import functools
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

cos = np.cos
sin = np.sin
pi = np.pi
bgcolor = '#252525'
active_color = 'red'
passive_color = 'white'


class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bgcolor)

        # Framing of the window
        self.l_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=bgcolor)
        self.l_frame.grid(column=0)
        self.r_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=bgcolor)
        self.r_frame.grid(column=1)

        self.slider_frame = []
        self.label = []
        self.entry = []
        self.slider = []

        self.elements = {"text": ["The initial body's semi-major axis", "The target body's semi-major axis", "The target body's period",
                                  "The parent's gravitational parameter", "Delta-v to perform the transfer"],
                         "color": ["green", "#1f77b4", "white", "white", "orange"]}

        for n in range(len(self.elements["text"])):
            slider_frame = tk.Frame(self.l_frame, bg=bgcolor)
            self.slider_frame.append(slider_frame)
            slider_frame.grid(pady=5)

            label = tk.Label(self.slider_frame[n], bg=bgcolor, text=self.elements["text"][n], font=("Arial", 10), fg='white')
            self.label.append(label)
            label.pack(anchor=tk.W)

            entry = tk.Entry(self.slider_frame[n], relief='flat', bg='grey', fg='black', validate="key")
            self.entry.append(entry)
            entry.pack(fill=tk.X)
            self.entry[n].bind("<Return>", functools.partial(self.set_slider, n))

            slider = tk.Scale(self.slider_frame[n], sliderrelief='flat', length=600, from_=1E-5, to=20, resolution=1E-5, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                              bd=0, highlightbackground=bgcolor, troughcolor=bgcolor, bg=self.elements["color"][n], sliderlength=40, showvalue=0,
                              activebackground=self.elements["color"][n], command=functools.partial(self.moved, n))
            self.slider.append(slider)
            slider.pack()

    def moved(self, n, value):
        s_value = float(value)
        self.write(n, value)
        print('called slider', n+1)
        if n == 0:
            self.slider[1].config(to=s_value*4)
            self.slider[1].set(float(s_value) * 2)

    def write(self, n, value):
        self.entry[n].delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry[n].insert(0, value)

    def set_slider(self, n, key):
        self.slider[n].set(self.entry[n].get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Transfer orbit calculator")
    root.geometry("1280x720")
    root.config(bg=bgcolor)
    root.iconbitmap("956255-200.ico")
    Interface(root).pack(expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

As you can ready (hopefully), I am now creating the different sliders, entries and labels based on a dictionary, allowing for shorter code. First, is this good practice or is this completely useless and adds pointless complexity?
I'd like to add that I plan on adding a couple more sliders to make it more precise over certain things, but that's not the subject here.

Second, my current problem is that I want to make the sliders behave the same way as they do in the first version I've done, which was:

Slider1 affects slider2, which is calculated using slider1 and slider3 and its properties 'from_' and 'to' so that it doesn't move but its value changes.

Slider2 affects slider3, which is calculated using slider1 and slider2

Slider3 affects slider2, which is recalculated using the new slider3 value and the current slider1. This time, the properties aren't affected.

I've been trying to find a way all day but I am not able to link them properly. So far, as you can see in the function moved(), what I have working is slider1 changing slider2 and its limits but when changing slider2 and then moving slider1, I can't find a way to change the calculations that would make slider2 static in its new location relative to the scale (like in the first version).

I'd really appreciate some help, and I am sorry if this is too much of a wall of text.

Comment: I got mainly everything except for two things: to be clear when changing slider1 slider2 stays in the place, correct or was that one of the issues? Second what happens if You have moved slider2 using slider1 and then You move slider2, how does that affect slider3? does slider3 move in parallel in that its current value is changing by the same amount the slider2's value is changing? also You should have provided a [mre].

Comment: I, thanks for answering. I have modified my question to replace the code for a cut down working version of the slider setup I need. This one is working as I would like the second version to, but I'm not able to. Sorry if I wasn't completely clear initially. Basically slider2 is calculated using slider1 and slider3, so if slider1 changes slider2 does too but not sliders3 although slider3 also affects slider2. And if slider2 moves, slider3 will be recalculated using slider1 and slider2. And yes, slider2 is supposed to stay in place whilst its value is changing when slider1 changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have further improved it using a global variable, which completely solves the problem of the delay.
So here is the code if it ever happens that anyone needs something similar:

```
import math
import functools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


bgcolor = '#252525'

slider_moved = 0


def moved_event(n, key):
    global slider_moved
    slider_moved = n


class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bgcolor)

        # Framing of the window
        self.l_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=bgcolor)
        self.l_frame.grid(column=0)
        self.r_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=bgcolor)
        self.r_frame.grid(column=1)
        self.graph1 = tk.Frame(self.r_frame, bg=bgcolor)
        self.graph2 = tk.Frame(self.r_frame, bg=bgcolor)

        self.slider_frame = []
        self.label = []
        self.entry = []
        self.slider = []

        self.elements = {"text": ["The initial body's semi-major axis", "The target body's semi-major axis", "The target body's period",
                                  "The parent's gravitational parameter", "Delta-v to perform the transfer"],
                         "color": ["green", "#1f77b4", "white", "white", "orange"]}

        for n in range(len(self.elements["text"])):
            slider_frame = tk.Frame(self.l_frame, bg=bgcolor)
            self.slider_frame.append(slider_frame)
            slider_frame.grid(pady=5)

            label = tk.Label(self.slider_frame[n], bg=bgcolor, text=self.elements["text"][n], font=("Arial", 10), fg='white')
            self.label.append(label)
            label.pack(anchor=tk.W)

            entry = tk.Entry(self.slider_frame[n], relief='flat', bg='grey', fg='black', validate="key")
            self.entry.append(entry)
            entry.pack(fill=tk.X)
            self.entry[n].bind("<Return>", functools.partial(self.set_slider, n))

            slider = tk.Scale(self.slider_frame[n], sliderrelief='flat', length=600, from_=1E-5, to=20, resolution=1E-5, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                              bd=0, highlightbackground=bgcolor, troughcolor=bgcolor, bg=self.elements["color"][n], sliderlength=40, showvalue=0,
                              activebackground=self.elements["color"][n], command=functools.partial(self.write, n))
            self.slider.append(slider)
            slider.pack()
            self.slider[n].bind("<Button>", functools.partial(moved_event, n))

        self.slider[0].set(10)
        self.slider[1].set(5)
        self.slider[2].set(2)
        self.slider[1].config(to=40)
        self.slider[2].config(to=4)

    def write(self, slider_updated, value):
        self.entry[slider_updated].delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry[slider_updated].insert(0, value)
        if slider_updated == slider_moved:
            if slider_updated == 0 or slider_updated == 2:
                self.slider[1].config(to=self.slider[0].get() * 4)
                self.slider[1].set(self.slider[0].get() / self.slider[2].get())
            if slider_updated == 1:
                self.slider[2].set(self.slider[0].get() / self.slider[1].get())

    def set_slider(self, n, key):
        self.slider[n].set(self.entry[n].get())
        moved_event(n, key)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Transfer orbit calculator")
    root.geometry("1280x720")
    root.config(bg=bgcolor)
    root.iconbitmap("956255-200.ico")
    Interface(root).pack(expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured out how to do it after a good night of sleep, here is a working version that uses the B1-Motion and ButtonRelease events instead of updating everytime one slider is moved because it would execute the command twice by just moving one slider.
This led to the value being used for the calculation not being the current one because of how things are processed.

```
class Interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bgcolor)

        # Framing of the window
        self.l_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=bgcolor)
        self.l_frame.grid(column=0)
        self.r_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg=bgcolor)
        self.r_frame.grid(column=1)
        self.graph1 = tk.Frame(self.r_frame, bg=bgcolor)
        self.graph2 = tk.Frame(self.r_frame, bg=bgcolor)

        self.slider_frame = []
        self.label = []
        self.entry = []
        self.slider = []

        self.elements = {"text": ["The initial body's semi-major axis", "The target body's semi-major axis", "The target body's period",
                                  "The parent's gravitational parameter", "Delta-v to perform the transfer"],
                         "color": ["green", "#1f77b4", "white", "white", "orange"]}

        for n in range(len(self.elements["text"])):
            slider_frame = tk.Frame(self.l_frame, bg=bgcolor)
            self.slider_frame.append(slider_frame)
            slider_frame.grid(pady=5)

            label = tk.Label(self.slider_frame[n], bg=bgcolor, text=self.elements["text"][n], font=("Arial", 10), fg='white')
            self.label.append(label)
            label.pack(anchor=tk.W)

            entry = tk.Entry(self.slider_frame[n], relief='flat', bg='grey', fg='black', validate="key")
            self.entry.append(entry)
            entry.pack(fill=tk.X)
            self.entry[n].bind("<Return>", functools.partial(self.set_slider, n))

            slider = tk.Scale(self.slider_frame[n], sliderrelief='flat', length=600, from_=1E-5, to=20, resolution=1E-5, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                              bd=0, highlightbackground=bgcolor, troughcolor=bgcolor, bg=self.elements["color"][n], sliderlength=40, showvalue=0,
                              activebackground=self.elements["color"][n], command=functools.partial(self.moved, n))
            self.slider.append(slider)
            slider.pack()
            self.slider[n].bind("<B1-Motion>", functools.partial(self.moved_event, n))
            self.slider[n].bind("<ButtonRelease>", functools.partial(self.moved_event, n))

        self.slider[0].set(5)
        self.slider[1].set(10)
        self.slider[2].set(2)

    def moved(self, n, value):
        self.write(n, value)
        print(self.slider[2].get())
        print('called slider', n+1)

    def moved_event(self, n, key):
        print("moved", n)
        s1_value = self.slider[0].get()
        s3_value = self.slider[2].get()
        if n == 0:
            self.slider[1].config(to=s1_value * 4)
            self.slider[1].set(s1_value * s3_value)
        if n == 1:
            s2_value = self.slider[1].get()
            self.slider[2].set(s2_value / s1_value)
        if n == 2:
            self.slider[1].set(s3_value * s1_value)

    def write(self, n, value):
        self.entry[n].delete(0, tk.END)
        self.entry[n].insert(0, value)

    def set_slider(self, n, key):
        self.slider[n].set(self.entry[n].get())
        self.moved_event(n, key)
```

The only problem which isn't a huge deal is that the slider updates using the previous value for slider2 and slider3 which means there is a little delay when moving incrementally. If someone knows how to deal with that, I'd be happy to hear it!